# AAD authentication to Azure Windows Server 2019 virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

I'm having issues authenticating my Azure Windows Server 2019 virtual machine with my AAD user.

According to Microsoft's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows, I've created Azure Windows Server 2019 VM using Terraform and installed Windows AAD authentication extension using:

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az vm extension set --publisher Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory --name AADLoginForWindows --resource-group ${data.azurerm_resource_group.RG.name} --vm-name ${var.prefix}"
  }
```

The machine is up and running and the extension installed successfully.
[image]

I've also assigned the appropriate role with users and groups in order to log in that VM with AAD authentication.
[image]

And ensured that my VMs network configuration permits outbound access over TCP port 443.

However, when trying to log in the VM with RDP and my AAD user (associated with the role) I get the error "The logon attempt failed" as shown above.

[image]

I'm trying to RDP Windows 10 VM from Windows 10 Pro VM.
[image]

My Windows 10 Pro VM is joined to Azure AD (with my AAD user). 
[image]

Yet, I get this error when RDP to the other Windows VM from my main Win10Pro VM.
When trying to login Linux VMs with AAD authentication everything works as expected.

Running the command "dsregcmd /status" from the Win10Pro VM gave the above output:
[image]

Also tried to RDP with "AzureAD\Username@Domain" but git the same credentials error.

What can be the problem?
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I had to configure both the Windows10Pro which I RDP from and the Windows10Pro which I RDP to be joined to Azure AD with my AAD user.
Only when I joined both VMs to AAD with my AAD user I could RDP with that user.

So in case of authenticating using AAD credentials to Windows VM some steps should be considered:

1. The machine which we RDP from should be Windows 10.
2. The machine which we RDP to should be Windows 10.
3. AADLoginForWindows extension should be installed on the remote VM.
   [image]
4. Login roles should be assigned with the AAD user/ group to the remote VM.
   [image]
5. Both machines should be Azure AD Joined or hybrid Azure AD joined.

Answer (score 1):

For the error, you could verify that the Windows 10 PC you are using to initiate the remote desktop connection is one that is either Azure AD joined, or hybrid Azure AD joined to the **same Azure AD directory** where your VM is joined to. For more information, see the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows#unauthorized-client).

Please note that

> Remote connection to VMs joined to Azure AD is only allowed from
>   Windows 10 PCs that are Azure AD joined or hybrid Azure AD joined to
>   the **same** directory as the VM. Additionally, to RDP using Azure AD
>   credentials, the user must belong to one of the two RBAC roles,
>   Virtual Machine Administrator Login or Virtual Machine User Login.

Comment: I tried to follow the documentation, not succeeded yet.
Updated the issue with the last configurations I've made.

Comment: Try to login with a username `AzureAD\USERNAME@DOMAIN.onmicrosoft.com` like [this](https://tech.xenit.se/how-to-rdp-into-a-azure-ad-joined-vm-in-azure/)?. Or try to run `dsregcmd /status` on the local Azure VM. The goal is for Device State to show as `AzureAdJoined : YES` and SSO State to show `AzureAdPrt : YES`. Here is a step by step tutorial in this [blog](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/sign-in-to-virtual-machine-in-azure-using-azure-active-directory-authentication)

Comment: Still got the same error when trying with "AzureAD\USERNAME@DOMAIN.onmicrosoft.com". When running the command I saw that the account is associated with Azure AD.

Comment: What you said `I'm trying to RDP Windows 10 VM from Windows 10 Pro VM.`? Did you RDP to that Azure VM server 2019 or windows 10?

Comment: Both, I've tried to RDP from my Windows10Pro to Windows10Pro Azure VM with no success and tried to RDP from Windows10Pro Azure VM to Windows 2019 Datacenter Azure VM with no success.